# Plotting 2 colored labels in time series plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series, seaborn, visualization

I have a dataset that includes the battery status (0 or 1) of a trip. I want to plot a time series plot that has discrete time for the x-axis and the vehicle speed at that time for the y-axis. There are some moments during the journey where the battery status will be 1 (charging) and at some moments it will be 0 (not charging). I've been trying to plot a time series plot that shows green when battery status is 0 and red for when battery status is 1. This is my code and results:

```
import seaborn as sns
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(35,5)) 
ax1=plt.subplot(121)

sns.lineplot(x='index', y='VehicleSpeed_km_h_', data=trip_1567) # plot normal time series plot
sns.lineplot(x='index', y= 'VehicleSpeed_km_h_', data=trip_1567[trip_1567['Battery_Status'] == 1], color='red')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used scatterplot instead.

```
import seaborn as sns
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(35,5)) 
ax1=plt.subplot(121)

sns.scatterplot(x='index', y='VehicleSpeed_km_h_', data=trip_1567, color='green') # plot normal time series plot
sns.scatterplot(x='index', y= 'VehicleSpeed_km_h_', data=trip_1567[trip_1567['Battery_Status'] == 1], color='red')
```

[image]